# Join two pyspark dataframes to select all the columns from the first df and some columns from the second df

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried importing two functions as shown below but I get an error

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col

df1 = sales.alias('a').join(customer.alias('b'),col('b.ID') == col('a.ID'))\
           .select([col('a.'+xx) for xx in sales.columns] + col('b.others')
```

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I really don't understand what's wrong with that line of code? Thanks.

Comment: could you past all df1 expression, because it's incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark select function expects only string column names and there is no need to send column objects as arrays. So you could just need to do this instead

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col

df1 = sales.alias('a').join(customer.alias('b'),col('b.ID') == col('a.ID'))\
           .select(sales.columns + ['others'])
```

Comment: For some reasons, its not working. And I changed my code as below and it works   `df1 = sales.join(customer, on=['ID']).select(sales.columns + ['others'])`             Some issues when I add `alias`